# Running .Net application from command prompt window

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, command-prompt

I have a .Net windows C# application, fairly complete and working, that I have been asked to support calling it from another program like LabView.  I have added the ability to parse command line arguments at startup so I can detect that it is supposed to behave like a console application and be provided with enough information to function.

What I would like to do is have the program print out to the console its results and have the calling program pipe it or just pull the data and use it.

The printing to the console works fine but when I start the program up, it tells the command prompt window that it is done (a new prompt immediately shows up and the command prompt is waiting for input).  In the process it also closes the redirection that was part of the startup line. Is there anyway to keep it from telling the calling program that it has completed before it has actually finished?

The simple solution is to pass a file to save the data to but I would prefer not to have to do that. I could also do a separate version that is a console app, but that means supporting two separate programs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking the program directly, you can use `cmd /c myapp.exe`.

Comment: The cmd option doesn't like to walk through the windows directories to find the command.  Even when properly quoted, it stops at the first blank (space) in a directory name.

Comment: @user3641293 I do not find that to be the case. `cmd /c "c:\Program Files (x86)\my app\my app.exe"` works.

Comment: If I remove all the spaces, it finds it.  I tried cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\ ... " and it complained the c:\Program is not an executable file.  I am running x86 command prompt on Windows 7.  On a positive note, cmd /c does wait for the program to finish, which is a major step in the right direction.

Comment: There are more than one set of quotes in the parameters ... the second set are for quoting the file path for the input file and that causes cmd to strip off the first set ... if I put a second set of quotes around everything it works.  Now if I can just get the redirection to work I will be good.